# Why am I missing information in network on production vs development in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

When in development build, I can inspect and go to the network tab, and I can see all sorts, like package information, or component information. That goes away in production. I'm curious why that is.

I tried to look into it from different sources, and from what I understood, it's that way during development to help with debugging and testing, but is removed during production, but I never found a good source that backed that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Development builds usually use source maps to link to source files for easy debugging during development, but it comes over performance which is not an issue during development. in the other hand, in production source maps are not useful and most modern build systems remove them, but you can opt out usually by setting a `sourcemap: true` in the build config

If you're using VueJS, I assume you're using Vite as build system, check out Build option: https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options#build-sourcemap